# Exponential of pauli x matrix using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to use MATLAB to take exponentials of a matrix, and I would've expected that the output of this program would give a 2x2 matrix with `cos(omega t)` on the diagonals, and `-i*sin(omega t)` on the off diagonals. But instead I'm getting `-sin(omega t)` on the off diagonals, without any imaginary unit. Anybody have an idea where I'm going wrong here?

```
syms omega t 
paulix = [ 0 1 ; 1 0 ];
U = expm(-1j*omega*t*paulix)
```

Comment: What is `omega`? What is `t`? Please [edit] your question to make this a complete [mcve]. The algorithm(s) for `expm` are linked in the docs, do they differ from whatever you've used to decide your expected outputs?

Comment: Apologies, they're just symbolic variables, have updated the code in my original post. I'm trying to create a time evolution unitary operator for the X gate in quantum computing, as described in here. https://medium.com/mdr-inc/time-evolution-operators-be2968493b86

In that website, if you ctrl+F "Single Qubit gates Z, X, Y" it's the R_x matrix that I am trying to reproduce in MATLAB. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Note that `sin(z) = (exp(iz)-exp(-iz)) / (2i)`. Your code gives `exp(-omega*t*1i)/2 - exp(omega*t*1i)/2` in the off-diagonal entries, which is `-i * sin(omega*t)`